# Looking to implement user management into my .net core api

Tags: asp.net-core, cqrs, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm looking at implementing user management into my .net core api that use cqrs+eventstore.

My thought:
Since i'll be using mongo for most of my domain models i thought why not use to store my users as well.

i.e. have a `CreateUser` command and  query service that subscribe to `UserCreated` event and store user in mongo.

I was hoping to use  ASP.NET Core Identity for my user management but everywhere i see identity, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity, it goes with asp.net mvc app. Which makes me think if do i even need Identity. I'll be exposing my api to various clients, mobile, web, etc.

Reading along there is also an IdentityServer4 which i don't quite get how it fits in.

Anyone to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You don't need to use MVC to use the Identity stuff.  Identity just uses entity framework to give you a few tables, and gives you some service classes for basic things like creating / updating users, authenticating them, managing claims, generating tokens for verifying an email address or requesting a password reset, things like that. I would definitely recommend using the built-in Identity - it's well thought out and easily customized to your needs.  It integrates well with MVC via authorization attributes, etc, but you don't have to use MVC to use Identity.

Comment: so what you saying is that i'll be using web api to perform those creating/updating etc. tasks through the likes of `UserManager.cs`, etc? i.e. (clients: web, mobile, etc) --> web api --> (Identity + EF)?

Comment: That's the idea, yeah.

Comment: where will identityserver4 fit in all this? also a discussion from here http://stackoverflow.com/q/39862314/7379424 mentions that it'll be adding cookie-based auth. anything wrong with that?

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing Identity framework and IdentityServer.  Identity framework just gives you tools to manage users within your app.  IdentityServer is more or less its own app that you can customize and run separately from your web api, then your web api can auth against it.  Either way you go, you can use tokens instead of cookies.  Tokens are generally preferred, as they're more scalable.  Here's a better analysis of tokens v cookies (I just googled it and skimmed, seemed ok).. https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-scalable-user-mgmt

Answer (score 0):

You don't need MVC in order to use Identity. I would recommend Identity Server (there is a good tutorial by its creator on Pluralsight).

You can very well have a Web API in .Net Core and use Identity Server to create tokens, etc. which is the recommended authentication mechanism when you want to expose to different clients (platforms).

Does it make sense?